# Can I get access to Davis Bacon Wage Determinations via this API?

Tags: labor

Can I get access to Davis Bacon Wage Determinations via the APIs at this site 'http://developer.dol.gov/wage-and-hour-division/wage-and-hour-publications-system'?  I am looking for recent and historical Davis Bacon wage determinations for select counties and trades.

Comment: What API are you referring to?

Comment: department of labor directs all of their users here; the wiki tag reinforces it (and confuses others) while their developer page brings them here with practically no context whatsover.

Comment: @Todd Read the above comment. You are on a different website now that has no relation with DOL. Can you [edit] your question so that is understandable to everyone here?

Answer (score 1):

Department of Labor (DOL) points to [WDOL (**W**age **D**eterminations **O**n**L**ine)](https://www.wdol.gov/) as the source of Davis-Bacon Determinations data.
[How do I subscribe to General Wage Discriminations Issued Under the Davis-Bacon and Related Acts?](https://www.dol.gov/whd/programs/dbra/faqs/subscrib.htm) says:

> "...the Department of Labor adopted the Wage Determination On Line (WDOL) website at https://wdol.gov as the source for obtaining Davis-Bacon Act (DBA) general wage determinations."

Another pseudo quote from DOL states:

> Bacon-Davis survey results for work done by DOL [are published/can be found at wdol.gov](http://www.wdol.gov/)

WDOL provides a single location for federal contracting officers to use in obtaining appropriate Service Contract Act (SCA) and Davis-Bacon Act (DBA) wage determinations (WDs) for each official contract action, and is available to the general public as well.

### References/Resources

Guidance in selecting WDs from this website is provided in the [wdol.gov User’s Guide (v6.0)](https://www.wdol.gov/usrguide/index.aspx).
[Selecting DBA Wage Decision - Find official wage rates as issued by the U.S. Department of Labor](https://www.wdol.gov/dba.aspx)
[Section C. Davis Bacon Act: Regulations and Requirements - wdol.gov Users' Guide (v6.0)](https://www.wdol.gov/usrguide/sectionc.aspx)
[Selecting DBA Wage Decisions](https://www.wdol.gov/dba.aspx) offers search by county.
[Latest Modifications/Additions to Davis-Bacon Database - DBA General Wage Determinations](https://www.wdol.gov/currentdba.aspx)
[Archived Davis-Bacon Act Wage Determinations](https://www.wdol.gov/archdba.aspx) goes back to 2000.
[Davis-Bacon Act Wage Determinations Due to be Revised](https://www.wdol.gov/newdba.aspx)
[Davis-Bacon and Related Acts - DOL WHD](https://www.dol.gov/whd/govcontracts/dbra.htm)
[Davis-Bacon Labor Standards - A Contractor's Guide to Prevailing Wage Requirements for Federally-Assisted Construction Projects (PDF)](https://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/documents/huddoc?id=4812-LRguide.pdf)
[Davis-Bacon Determinations  - U.S. Department of Labor Prevailing Wage Resource Book - DB Wage Determinations (PDF)](https://www.dol.gov/whd/recovery/pwrb/Tab6.pdf)